# How do I connect a database in MongoDB to Dialogflow?

Tags: mongodb, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am creating a chatbot that integrates Mongodb as its database. I have been looking for code that connects a MongoDB database to Dialogflow so that I could create functions for the intents I have been making. I will put the code via the in-line editor of Dialogflow. How do I make this connection? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Inline editor just creates cloud function in node.js. Are you asking how to connect from it or you are trying to connect already, but due to some reasons is not possible.

Comment: oh yes! im asking about the connection of the Dialogflow Fulfillment (inline editor) and mongodb. When I try other codes I would get an error upon deployment

Comment: Can you  add minimal example code and error its results? Otherwise it will be hard to guess whats the issue.